# Does "study confirmation" works for my purpose?

Tags: phrase-request

I am originally from one country but study at university in a different country. Now, my native country asked me to prove that I study at this university and I want to ask my university to bring me document for that. Can I call this document "*study confirmation letter*" or "confirmation of studies" and simply ask them for that and they will understand?

Comment: What about "study abroad sanction letter"? I am not sure however.

Comment: They want confirmation that I study. The emphasize is on the studies rather than on the country. Think about that governmental office in your country asks from you to bring a document for proving your studies.

Comment: I found this "Proof of Study" - does it work? http://www.cambridgestudents.cam.ac.uk/your-course/graduate-study/your-student-status/confirmation-study-verification-letters

Comment: It seems that it's what your are looking for, but I think it's not a bad idea to ask this question on Acadmia: https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good idea. I'll try it.

Comment: I found also "Certificates of Enrolment" - https://www.stir.ac.uk/registry/studentinformation/confirmationdocuments/

Comment: The best advice you will receive is to ask this question at the **[Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)** Stackexchange site. Someone there will have satisfied the same request and will have reliable advice for you.

Comment: I found also "proof of enrolment" - http://www.southampton.ac.uk/studentservices/letter-requests/confirmation-of-study.page

Comment: "Proof of Enrollment" is the correct term for this. Additionally "Proof of Attendance" or "Proof of Enrollment and Attendance", since it's not terribly uncommon for a foreign student to enroll in an educational program and then not attend. It may satisfy your home country more than a simple Proof of Enrollment.

Comment: Different institutions will use different expressions. This is not written in stone. Proof of attendance [at another university].

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91681/the-name-of-the-document-which-prove-my-studies-at-the-university/91685#91685